# How to host an express app which uses redis to manage session?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, hosting, pm2

I have built an express application for a Home Services Management. It uses session for authorization and as a session store uses redis. Now, i don't have too much knowledge about redis, i just know till its usage as a session storage. Before running my express application, I have to run redis-server command to kickstart the server.

It works completely fine on my localhost, but I want to host it on web, but i can't figure out how to solve this redis-server command issue.

I tried using pm2 and it works great with too on localhost, but I don't know how to replicate this in a serverless environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a hosted Redis instance from various places and use that.  These places include (but probably aren't limited to):

- redis.com (full disclosure - this is my employer)
- Google Cloud (Google Cloud Memory Store)
- AWS (Elasticache)
- Aiven
- Upstash

When considering these you want to make sure that your code is running as "close" as possible to Redis to minimize network latency.  Some providers offer Redis in multiple clouds (examples: redis.com, Aiven).

Also take a look at what your serverless code platform offers.  For example Cloudflare have their own key/value product that works with Cloudflare workers.

Additionally, you could use somewhere that allows deployment of Docker containers and deploy your application and Redis as containers.  Redis plays nicely in a Docker container.

Make sure to check that any provider you're considering offers the Redis data types that your application uses.